# Converting integer to unsigned char* (int 221 to "\xdd")

Tags: c, types

I have a function which takes `unsigned char*` as input.

Say for example that I have:

```
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) "\xdd";
int a = 221;
```

How can I convert my integer `a` to `unsigned char*` such that `data` and my converted `a` is indistinguishable? 
I have tried playing around with sprintf but without any luck, I'm not sure how to handle the "\x" part.

Comment: With `sprintf()`, something like `unsigned char res[5]; sprintf(res,"\\x%02x",a & 0xff);` (for just the low byte of `a`).  Maybe you were missing the `\\x` part of the format string?  There are other ways to do it, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `221` is not guaranteed to be a valid value for a `char` type, the closest thing you can do is:

```
 int a = 221;
 unsigned char buffer[10];
 sprintf((char*)buffer, "%c", a);
```

Here's an example program and its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) "\xdd";
    int a = 221;
    unsigned char buffer[10];
    sprintf((char*)buffer, "%c", a);
    printf("%d\n", buffer[0] == data[0]);
    printf("%d\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("%d\n", data[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
1
221
221
```

**Update**

Perhaps I misunderstood your question. You can also use:

```
 int a = 221;
 unsigned char buffer[10] = {0};
 buffer[0] = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated the question does not make sense and is not possible - you don't actually want to convert to `const char *`, which is a pointer type. Instead you want to convert into an array of `char`s and then take the address of that array by using its name.

```
int x = 221;
char buf[5];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "\\x%.2x", x);
/* now pass buf to whatever function you want, e.g.: */
puts(buf);
```

Comment: Hopefully `0 <= x < 256`, else `buf[]` overflow.

Comment: @chux: No, it gets truncated because I used the correct function, `snprintf`, rather than the deprecated `sprintf` OP suggested. From the context I took it that the integer was supposed to represent a byte value, but if that's not the case then by all means use a larger buffer.

Comment: Based on the other answer, though, I'm not clear on whether this is even what OP wanted.

Comment: Not sure the OP knows what s/he wants. The contents of `buf` in this answer will certainly not match the contents of `data` from the question.

Comment: This is almost certainly wrong... the string `"\xdd"` corresponds to the decimal value 221.